# Problem installing TeamViewer for Linux in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: apt, dependencies

New convert from Windows 10 to Ubuntu so be gentle with me!!!

I do work in IT support but have no experience with Linux other than just installing Ubuntu.

I am trying to install Teamviewer for Linux as I'm in UK and my girlfriend is on Windows 10 machine in USA and I need to remote onto her machine.

I have successfully downloaded the .deb 15.5.3 package from https://download.teamviewer.com/download/linux/teamviewer_amd64.deb

I have opened the terminal and ran

```
$ cd /home/pete/Downloads
~/Downloads$ sudo apt install ./teamviewer_15.5.3_amd64.deb
```

but it returns the following errors...

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 messengerfordesktop : Depends: libappindicator1 but it is not installed or
                                libappindicator but it is not installable or
                                libappindicator-gtk3 but it is not installable
                       Depends: gconf2
                       Depends: gconf-service
                       Depends: python
                       Recommends: hunspell
                       Recommends: git
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I have tried `apt --fix-broken install` but get the following errors

```
$ apt --fix-broken install
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

HELP!!!

Thanks

Kind regards

Pete

Comment: `messengerfordesktop` and `teamviewer` are not the same application. What was real output of `sudo apt install ./teamviewer_15.5.3_amd64.deb`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository). Looks like your uninstallables are in -universe. Reminder: You can have only ONE package manager open at a time (that's what the 'lock' error is about).

Comment: @user535733 the lock error is probably due to him not running `apt --fix-broken install` as root. Note the lack of `sudo` in front of it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process)

Comment: Thanks guys. I had already successfully installed messenger for desktop and has been running fine. Those errors are exactly as it appeared in the terminal. So if I ran sudo apt --fix-broken install, that would work? Not sure about universe, I'll have to read up on that aspect

Answer (score 0):

You should use `sudo` after now for every command or just enter as sudo typing `sudo su`.

Ok, you just need to first install the package, and then fix dependencies.

Install the package using `sudo dpkg -i "whereisthepackage"`. (if you typed before `sudo su`, sudo won't ask you the password, because you are logged in as root. To exit from this behavior, and regret to your account, you just need to type `exit` and you will be on you account.)

Then fix the dependencies by typing `sudo apt install --fix-broken`. Add `-y` to the end of the command if you don't want to be asked if yes or not install some packages.

Answer (score 0):

`apt` is primarily designed for installing programs from the online repositories. For installing local DEB packages from the command-line, the default program is `dpkg`. However, I'd recommend the `gdebi` program from the `gdebi-core` package instead of `dpkg`. It is similar to `dpkg` however unlike `dpkg` it automatically resolves the necessary dependencies before installing.

To install `gdebi`, run `sudo apt install gdebi-core`.

To install your local DEB package, now run `sudo gdebi <PackageName>.deb`. Make sure to replace `<PackageName>` with the actual name of the package.